# PHP loop through JSON response and insert into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, loops, foreach

For a school project I want to loop through a JSON response and insert the data into a MySQL database.

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{"tableID":100965,"data":[{"updated_at":1506994152000,"prices":{"unstable_reason":"LOW_SALES","unstable":true,"sold":{"avg_daily_volume":null,"last_90d":67,"last_30d":52,"last_7d":15,"last_24h":1},"max":287.5,"avg":93.52,"min":51.01,"latest":87},"image":"IMGURL","db_name":"Test-Artikel","dbID":"123456789"},{"updated_at":1506994152000,"prices":{"unstable_reason":"LOW_SALES","unstable":true,"sold":{"avg_daily_volume":null,"last_90d":67,"last_30d":52,"last_7d":15,"last_24h":1},"max":287.5,"avg":93.52,"min":51.01,"latest":87},"image":"IMGURL","db_name":"Test-Artikel","dbID":"123456789"}],"__v":0,"createdAt":"2017-03-27T09:16:48.395Z"}
```

Every array should be a own row in the mysql database.

Currently i'm able to get one information out of the json file with this code:

```
<?php
$url = "linktojson";

//connect to database
//$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=...', '...', '...');

//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);   

echo('<pre>');
foreach ($data['data'] as $api_data) {
    echo $api_data['name'] . '<br/>';

}
?>
```

EDIT:
Current Code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX');
$yourJsonArray ="test.json";
$dataArray = json_decode(json_encode($yourJsonArray),true);
foreach($dataArray as $key => $value){
   $image = $key['image'];
   $statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO api_data (image) VALUES (?)'); 
   $statement->execute(array($image));
}
```

Error MSG: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in test.php on line 29

Line 29 = foreach (got some old comments on top)

EDIT: Added `var_dump($yourJsonArray);` before foreach:

```
string(638) "{"tableID":100965,"data":[{"updated_at":1506994152000,"prices":{"unstable_reason":"LOW_SALES","unstable":true,"sold":{"avg_daily_volume":null,"last_90d":67,"last_30d":52,"last_7d":15,"last_24h":1},"max":287.5,"avg":93.52,"min":51.01,"latest":87},"image":"IMGURL","db_name":"Test-Artikel","dbID":"123456789"},{"updated_at":1506994152000,"prices":{"unstable_reason":"LOW_SALES","unstable":true,"sold":{"avg_daily_volume":null,"last_90d":67,"last_30d":52,"last_7d":15,"last_24h":1},"max":287.5,"avg":93.52,"min":51.01,"latest":87},"image":"IMGURL","db_name":"Test-Artikel","dbID":"123456789"}],"__v":0,"createdAt":"2017-03-27T09:16:48.395Z"}"
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in test.php on line 30
```

EDIT: changed $dataArray to `$dataArray = json_decode($yourJsonArray,true);`

Error (4x):
Warning: Illegal string offset 'image' in test.php on line 33

line 33 = `$image = $key['image'];`

EDIT: I dumped the $key Var and got this:

```
string(7) "tableID" string(4) "data" string(3) "__v" string(9) "createdAt"
```

How do i get the Elements of "data"?

Comment: I know how to loop trough the file and one element (e.g. "name") from every array. 
echo('<pre>');
 foreach ($data['data'] as $name) {
  echo $name['name'] . '<br/>';
 }
I' can't find a proper way to get all the elements i need.

Comment: you have 'the json response 'looks like this` ' but that is no json. Put the real thing so people can help you, not what you think you are getting, or what you think you are producing at 'linktojson'.

Comment: Aight. I get your point - added the first two elements of the json file to my question.

Comment: ahhh ... his eyes have seen (and jsonlint thinks this json is valid) ! so, it would appear that the `$api_data` array does not have a `name` property. Did you mean `db_name` ?

Comment: haha.. the php code from my question is 'outdated' - im using db_name now.

Comment: your json and your code work for me. Only thing i can see is if your file_get_contents fails somehow and your $jsondata is not what you think it is (again). You should echo/log it , and verify it with jsonlint.

Comment: if i could downvote this another time i would : you dont make it easy do you ? first no json, then wrong code.

Comment: if you would understand my question, that would be great. if you downvote this - why do you still comment and "try to help me"?

Answer (score 4):

Try like this :

```
$yourJsonArray = "You Json Array will come here";
//$dataArray = json_decode(json_encode($yourJsonArray),true);
$dataArray = json_decode($yourJsonArray,true); 
foreach($dataArray as $key => $value){
   //Here 0,1,2,3 Will be contained inside the $key variable.
   //Code to insert the data comes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you - i'll give it a go!

Comment: I tried it but i'm getting an error (see my question above)

Comment: @FelixSchwie Can you `var_dump($yourJsonArray)` before sending it into `foreach()` ?

Comment: @FelixSchwie I have edited the answer, remove the `var_dump()`.

Comment: Added new ErrorMSG to question